# django modelformset_factory POST request data retrieval

Tags: python, django

I currently got django 1.9 and I found out modelformset_factory very useful as I can setup forms without major afford.

Now I came to realise upon submitting the form (POST method)I need to figure out which objects I have added and removed .

This is the view I got :

```
def def_accounts(request):

    list_services_list()
    services_list_TopicFormSet = modelformset_factory(services_list, form=services_list_nameForm, fields=('accounts',), can_delete=True)
    items = services_list.objects.all()
    formset = services_list_TopicFormSet(queryset = items)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        t_formset = services_list_TopicFormSet(request.POST)
        if t_formset.is_valid():
            t_formset.save()
```

I have looked into the POST request and it seems a full data submission, it seems doing a full object refresh so I cannot really distinguish the POST action in there..

Any help on this?

Thanks!

***EDIT***
It seems I can figure which object are being added to toe FORM as follows:

```
    if t_formset.is_valid():
        instances = t_formset.save()
        for instance in instances:
             print "instance.id: " + str(instance.id)
             print "instance.accounts: " + str(instance.accounts)
             instance.save()
```

output:

```
> instance.id: 21
> instance.accounts: test1
```

Still trying to figure out how can I get which objects are being deleted!

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, or what it has to do with the factory specifically.

Comment: I have added an EDIT to the original question. I managed to get some details about an added object to the form, but I cannot manage to get details when the objects gets deleted/removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [save a model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) by calling `formset.save()`, you get three attributes `formset.changed_objects`, `formset_deleted_objects` and `formset.new_objects` which store the changed, deleted and new objects respectively.

Therefore, you can access the deleted objects with `formset.deleted_objects`.

Comment: thanks very much for that! I am still learning the inside-outs of django and it's taking a bit of time to get familiar with the way it operates and it's documented.